# shellcheck is advising not to use basename: why?

Tags: shell, filenames, posix, basename

I am trying out [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net).

I have something like that

```
basename "${OPENSSL}"
```

and I get the following suggestion

```
Use parameter expansion instead, such as ${var##*/}.
```

From the practical point of view I see no difference

```
$ export OPENSSL=/opt/local/bin/openssl
$ basename ${OPENSSL}
openssl
$ echo ${OPENSSL##*/}
openssl
```

Since `basename` is in the [POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/basename.html), I don't a reason why it should be best practice. Any hint?

Comment: It forks a new process when it doesn't need to.

Comment: @jordanm fair enough ... I didn't think about efficiency.

Comment: @jordanm On the other hand it works with on shells other than bash

Comment: @Matteo so does `${OPENSSL##*/}`. Not sure on which but definitely in zsh and probably others.

Comment: @terdon Parameter expansion is [in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Comment: @JosephR. that's what I thought but just found out that it does not work on `csh`. I guess `csh` is not POSIX then.

Comment: @terdon - csh is very far from POSIX.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253524/135943, but the answers here and there cover different aspects and complement each other nicely.

Comment: Answer to both question (here and there) don't consider that basename can also strip a given file extension. Furthermore at least the gnu version can ouptut a null delimiter instead of a newline (`-z` option).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not about efficiency -- it's about correctness. `basename` uses newlines to delimit the filenames it prints out. In the usual case when you only pass one filename, it adds a trailing newline to its output. Since filenames may contain newlines themselves, this makes it difficult to correctly handle these filenames.

It's further complicated by the fact that people usually use `basename` like this: `"$(basename "$file")"`. This makes things even more difficult, because `$(command)` strips *all* trailing newlines from `command`. Consider the unlikely case that `$file` ends with a newline. Then `basename` will add an extra newline, but `"$(basename "$file")"` will strip *both* newlines, leaving you with an incorrect filename.

Another problem with `basename` is that if `$file` begins with a `-` (dash a.k.a. minus), it will be interpreted as an option. This one is easy to fix: `$(basename -- "$file")`

The robust way of using `basename` is this:

```
# A file with three trailing newlines.
file=$'/tmp/evil\n\n\n'

# Add an 'x' so we can tell where $file's newlines end and basename's begin.
file_x="$(basename -- "$file"; printf x)"

# Strip off two trailing characters: the 'x' added by us and the newline added by basename. 
base="${file_x%??}"
```

An alternative is to use `${file##*/}`, which is easier but has bugs of its own. In particular, it's wrong in the cases where `$file` is `/` or `foo/`.

Comment: Very good points, +1. Glad the OP accepted this instead of mine.

Comment: Counterpoint: what if `$file` is `foo/`? What if it's `/`?

Comment: @Gilles: You're right. I'm starting to think that the `basename` approach is better after all, as hacky as it is. The best alternatives I can come up with are `${${${file}%%/#}##*/}` and `[[ $file =~ "([^/]*)/*$" ]] && printf "%s" $match[1]`, both of which are zsh-specific and neither of which handle `/` correctly.

Comment: @terdon Thanks that you didn't take it personally :-). Files with newlines are not common but Matt has a point. Of course using variable substitution is also more efficient.

Answer (score 17):

The relevant lines in `shellcheck`'s [source code](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/blob/master/ShellCheck/Analytics.hs) are:

```
checkNeedlessCommands (T_SimpleCommand id _ (w:_)) | w `isCommand` "dirname" =
    style id "Use parameter expansion instead, such as ${var%/*}."
checkNeedlessCommands (T_SimpleCommand id _ (w:_)) | w `isCommand` "basename" =
    style id "Use parameter expansion instead, such as ${var##*/}."
checkNeedlessCommands _ = return ()
```

There is no explanation given explicitly but based on the name of the function (`checkNeedlessCommands`) it looks like @jordanm is quite right and it is suggesting you avoid forking a new process.

Comment: May the source be with you :)

Answer (score 3):

`dirname`, `basename`, `readlink` etc (thanks @Marco - this is corrected) can create portability problems when security becomes important (requiring security of the path).  Many systems (like Fedora Linux) place it at `/bin` whereas others (like Mac OSX) place it at `/usr/bin`.  Then there is Bash on Windows, eg cygwin, msys, and others.  <del>It's always better to stay pure Bash, when possible.</del> (per @Marco comment)

BTW, thanks for the pointer to shellcheck, I haven't seen that before.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by “security”? Can you elaborate? 2) The OP does not mention `dirname` at all. 3) Basic core utilities should be in the PATH, wherever they are stored. I haven't yet seen a system where `basename` was not in the PATH. 4) Assuming bash is available is a portibility issue. It's always better to stay away from bash and use a POSIX shell when portability is required.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for pointing out these issues.  Yes you are correct that the utilities are on the path.  But where one wants to provide added security to a Bash script, it's good practice to provide the absolute path.  So calling '/bin/basename' will work for RedHat systems, but it will produce an error on a Mac.  This is better explained in the [Bash Cookbook](http://bashcookbook.com/) where about one quarter of the 600 pages is devoted to this subject.  We have made a rough attempt to address the security issues there in our free source [secure-lib](http://asymlabs.github.io/secure-lib/).

Comment: @Marco Point 4 is a valid comment but the question (OP) begins with and is written around [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) which is designed to check both sh/bash scripts.  Therefore we have to assume it is not strictly Posix by default.

Comment: @Marco Security of the path environment variable can be compromised easily.  For example, I was very surprised to find some years ago that the Ruby RVM, installed locally, by default placed it's path before the system path.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions POSIX and the question is tagged `posix` and not `bash`. I fail to find any indicator that the OP requires a bash solution. Your statement “It's always better to stay pure Bash” is just plain wrong, I'm sorry.

Comment: @ Marco Point well made and accepted in the context of this thread.  It could also be argued that [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) was not the correct tool in this case.