# split a string into path and application

Tags: bash, debian, split

If I have a string such as

```
/home/user/a/directory/myapp.app
```

or just

```
/home/user/myapp.app
```

how can I split this so that I just have two variables (the path and the application)

e.g.

```
path="/home/user/"
appl="myapp.app"
```

I've seen numerous examples of splitting strings, but how can I get just the last part, and combine all the rest?

Comment: Did you try `dirname` and `basename`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The commands `basename` and `dirname` can be used for that, for example:

```
$ basename /home/user/a/directory/myapp.app 
myapp.app
$ dirname /home/user/a/directory/myapp.app 
/home/user/a/directory
```

For more information, do not hesitate to do `man basename` and `man dirname`.

Comment: You beat me to it :) LOL.

Comment: 27 seconds faster than me. damn :)

Comment: Sorry for that, I got luck I think. :-)

Comment: cheers quys, I figured it would be something simple that I'd overlooked, but not quite that simple!!

Comment: Somethimes, you just need to forget about strings, and use the manpages to quick look to what you nee ;) `man -k "pathname"` should be enough to help you on this.

Answer (score 6):

With any POSIX shell:

```
$ str=/home/user/a/directory/myapp.app
$ path=${str%/*}
$ app=${str##*/}
$ printf 'path is: %s\n' "$path"
path is: /home/user/a/directory
$ printf 'app is: %s\n' "$app"
app is: myapp.app
```

save you for two processes forking.

In case of `/myapp.app`, `myapp.app` and `/path/to/myapp.app`, `basename`/`dirname` are more graceful. See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253524/38906) for more discussion.