# How do I remove a . from the start of a Bash string and write the result to a variable?

Tags: shell-script, directory

I am presently writing a shell function and it would help me in writing it to be able to remove a `.` from the start of a folder name (changing the folder name from that of a hidden folder to that of a non-hidden folder). The folder name is stored in the variable `$CWD`, which itself is evaluated using:

```
CWD=${PWD##*/}
```

I would like to call the variable that equals `$CWD` without the `.` at its start `$GWD`. Presently I am trying to do this using `sed`, but I am open to any solution to this problem. This is what I have been trying:

```
GWD=$(sed -i 's/.*//' $CWD)
```

I have also tried substituting `'` in this expression with `"` and I have tried substituting `-i` with `-e`. But this keeps returning the error:

```
sed: can't read .atom: No such file or directory
```

where `CWD='.atom'` for me at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GWD="${CWD#.}"`

Your sed command didn't work because it wanted to read the *file* defined in `$CWD`. You would have wanted to `echo $CWD | sed 's/^[\.]//'`

You might also be interested in [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253524/dirname-and-basename-vs-parameter-expansion) which will help you get `CWD` more robustly.