# Bash for file processing

Tags: bash, variable, basename, dirname

I am writing a bash script to move all images into a central file.

I create the list of image files with:

```
img_fil='/home/files/img_dump.txt'
locate -i image | grep \.jpg > "$img_fil"
locate -i image | grep \.jpeg >> "$img_fil"
locate -i image | grep \.gif >> "$img_fil"
locate -i image | grep \.tif >> "$img_fil"
locate -i image | grep \.png >> "$img_fil"
```

But when I start processing the dump file for this, most of the paths contain blanks so this does not work:

```
while read -r fline
do
   if [ ! -e "$fline" ]; then
      echo "F=> $fline"
      mv "$fline" "$img_dir"
   else
      fpath="$(dirname $fline)"
      fname="$(basename $fline)"
      echo "F=> $fname P=> $fpath"
   fi 
done
```

The dirname and basename always parse at the blanks so will not process right.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: `locate -0 \.jpg \.jpeg | xargs -0 ...` might help here. Also, `find ~ ...` might be more accurate.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the variables inside your command substitutions?  i.e. `fpath=$(dirname "$fline")` and `fname=$(basename "$fline")`

Answer (score 2):

```
fpath="$(dirname $fline)"
fname="$(basename $fline)"
```

Here, you need to quote `$fline` inside the command substitution. (Outside doesn't matter since it's in an assignment.) So:

```
fpath=$(dirname -- "$fline")
```

or

```
fpath=${fline%/*}
```

(Though note the minor differences between `dirname`/`basename` and the parameter expansions, see: [dirname and basename vs parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253524/170373) )

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using `$img_fil` in your script? Shouldn't the line `done` be `done < "$img_fil"`?

Comment: Might be `cat img_dump.txt | script.sh`