# Delete everything before last slash in bash variable

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, tar

I have a variable `myVar` in bash containing a long string that looks like this:

```
-rw-rw-rw- root/root 16 2018-02-12 10:03 foo_tar/baz1234_
```

**I want to delete everything in `myVar` before the last slash *(including the last slash)***, so that `myVar` ends up storing only `baz1234_`. How can I remove everything and store the result in a variable?

I have encountered solutions dealing with sed, but those tackle file handling, hence my question.

Comment: This looks like a XY Problem.  If you need the filename only, don't parse the output of `ls -l`.  What is exactly your need?

Comment: I have a folder full of `tar` archives, each one of them containing multiple files. I loop through them as to get a specific file that starts with `baz`, is followed by some digits and finally with an underscore `_`. Inside each `tar` archive there is one such file, for which I want to get the name and output it on a csv file. I get the aforementioned output using the `tar` command, looking for that specific file, but get that long string, for which I only want the final part. I store that in a variable, and print it then, alongside other information, on a csv file.

Comment: for deleting upto last slash, one can also use `basename -- "$myVar"`

Comment: But see also [dirname and basename vs parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253524/170373) and [shellcheck is advising not to use basename: why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94295/170373)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `bash` [Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for this and use sub-string removal of type `${PARAMETER##PATTERN}`

> From the beginning - `${PARAMETER##PATTERN}`
>
> This form is to remove the described pattern trying to match it from the beginning of the string. The `##` tries to do it with the longest text matching.

Using for your example

```
$ myVar='-rw-rw-rw- root/root 16 2018-02-12 10:03 foo_tar/baz1234_'
$ echo "${myVar##*/}"
baz1234_
```

---

As noted in the comments, the string in question seems to be output of `ls` command in a variable! which is not an ideal scripting way. Explain your requirement a bit more clearly.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works and does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I have a folder full of `tar` archives, each one of them containing multiple files. I loop through them as to get a specific file that starts with `baz`, is followed by some digits and finally with an underscore `_`. Inside each `tar` archive there is one such file, for which I want to get the name and output it on a csv file. I get the aforementioned output using the tar command, looking for that specific file, but get that long string, for which I only want the final part. I store that in a variable, and print it then, alongside other information, on a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Awk solution:

```
myVar='-rw-rw-rw- root/root 16 2018-02-12 10:03 foo_tar/baz1234_'
myVar=$(echo "$myVar" |  awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')
```

However as others have pointed out, having the output of ls stored as a variable isn't a great idea - if you can provide more context to the script we should be able to advise better solutions

Comment: I have a folder full of `tar` archives, each one of them containing multiple files. I loop through them as to get a specific file that starts with `baz`, is followed by some digits and finally with an underscore `_`. Inside each `tar` archive there is one such file, for which I want to get the name and output it on a csv file. I get the aforementioned output using the tar command, looking for that specific file, but get that long string, for which I only want the final part. I store that in a variable, and print it then, alongside other information, on a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> I have a folder full of tar archives, each one of them containing multiple files. I loop through them as to get a specific file that starts with baz, is followed by some digits and finally with an underscore _

So is that listing the output of `tar tzvf foo.tar.gz` or such?
My `tar` outputs only the file names with `tar t ...` (without `v` for verbose), so you could just do something like this to get the file name instead of using the shell to process the output line-by-line:

```
tar tzf foo.tar.gz |grep -E '/baz[0-9]+_$' |sed -e 's,.*/,,'
```

(or capture it with command substitution: `filename=$(tar ... | sed ...)` and of course, you can replace the `sed` with the parameter expansion `${filename##./}`.)